# Magento uses default/default as skin theme in newsletter instead of site theme default/my_theme?

Tags: email, templates, magento

I was testing the admin password retrieval email template and the message Magento sent to my admin email uses **default/default/images/logo_email.gif** as the logo. However, my current site theme is default/my_theme so I thought it should use **default/my_theme/images/logo_email.gif** but it didn't.

I then tried some other email templates such as new account creation and user password retrieval templates and they are all fine with default/my_theme logo rather than the default/default one.

Is there a problem or is it by design that admin emails use everything in default/default rather than my specified theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you didn't state which area your theme settings refer to. I'm assuming you are referring to the frontend store view configuration.

The email is sent by the method `Mage_Admin_Model_User::sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()`
This method calls `$mailer->setStoreId(0)`, which causes Magento to look for the theme configured for the `adminhtml` area.
This defaults to `default/default` in according to *Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml* in the node `stores/admin/design/package/name` and `stores/admin/design/theme/default`.

If you are using a Magento version including the Find_Feed extension (in the community code pool), it (stupidly) specifies the admin theme `default/find` in it's config.xml.

So this gives you the full path
`skin/adminthml/default/default/images/logo_email.gif` or `skin/adminthml/default/find/images/logo_email.gif`.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies it all.